# Python Multiprocessing Management

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm fairly familiar with the python multiprocessing module, but I'm unsure of how to implement this setup. My project has this basic flow:

request serial device -> gather response -> parse response -> assert response -> repeat

It is right now a sequential operation that loops over this until it has gather the desired number of asserted responses. I was hoping to speed this task up by having a 'master process' do the first two operations, and then pass off the parsing and assertion task into a queue of worker processes. However, this is only beneficial if the master process is ALWAYS running. I'm guaranteed to be working on a multi-core machine.

Is there any way to have a process in the multiprocessing module always have focus / make run so I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You fire to processes which run forever and communicate with each other. Can you explain where's the issue?

Comment: If I understand how processes work correctly, when you create multiple processes their focus (from a processor perspectice) is arbitrary. IE if I recieved 4 responses and passed the parsing onto workers, there could be a time in which my 4-core processor is only working on the parsing jobs, not the serial communication process. I was hoping there was a way to assure that the serial communication process is always within processor focus.

Comment: You cannot force a processor to focus on a given process (at least not under reasonable OS). But you misunderstand something: it's not that processor will focus on these 4 processes until they finish the job. Context switching takes place in the middle of a job (that's why you can open for example 10 movie players and all of them work at the same time). So you should not worry about that, your server won't get blocked.

Comment: I understand that, I must have misphrased my question. But I suppose it is out of reason to block context switching for one task. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Maybe it's me who doesn't understand the problem. If you want you can rephrase it and I will think about it one more time. Cheers! P.S. If you want the other process to wait for the first one you can simply use locks.

Comment: Is this a hard real-time application? Do you have stringent limits on how long it takes to handle the serial communications before you start losing data?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather (assuming that you don't have a stringent requirement that the master is **always** logging the data from the serial device) you just want the master to be ready to give any worker a chunk of data and be ready to receive data from any worker as soon as the worj=ker is ready.

to acheive this use two queus and multiprocessing

[Multiprocessing Queue in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672525/multiprocessing-queue-in-python)

[How to use multiprocessing queue in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515944/how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-in-python)

this should be sufficient fro your needs if time(parse data)>>gather data

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to implement your workflow:

1. Have two `multiprocessing.Queue` objects: **tasks_queue** and
   **results_queue**. The **tasks_queue** will hold device outputs, and **results_queue** will hold results of the assertions.
2. Have a pool of workers, where each worker pulls device output from
   **tasks_queue**, parses it, asserts, and puts the result of assertion on the **results_queue**.
3. Have another process continuously polling device and put device
   output on the **tasks_queue**.
4. Have one last process continuously polling **results_queue**, and
   ending the overall program when the desired number of resuts (successful
   assertions) is reached.

Total number of processes (`multiprocessing.Process` objects) is 2 + *k*, where *k* is the number of workers in the pool.