# Running 1000 functions gracefully using python multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to receive stock data for about 1000 stocks, to speed up the process I'm using multiprocessing, unfortunately due to the large amount of stock data I'm trying to receive python as a whole just crashes.

Is there a way to use multiprocessing without python crashing, I understand it would still take some time to do all of the 1000 stocks, but all I need is to do this process as fast as possible.

```
import threading
import yfinance as yf
from multiprocessing import Process

database = {}
mylock = threading.RLock()
stocks = ['AAU', 'ABEO', 'ABEV', 'ABIO', 'ABUS', 'ACCO', 'ACER', 'ACIU', 'ACOR', 'ACRX', 'ACST', 'ACTG', 'ADAP', 'ADIL', 'ADMA', 'ADMP', 'ADT', 'ADTX', 'ADXS', 'AEG', 'AEHL', 'AEHR', 'AEMD', 'AESE', 'AEY', 'AEZS', 'AFIN', 'AFMD', 'AGEN', 'AGI', 'AGRO', 'AGRX', 'AGS', 'AGTC', 'AHPI', 'AHT', 'AIHS', 'AIKI', 'AIM', 'AINC', 'AIRI', 'AIV', 'AKBA', 'AKER', 'AKTX', 'ALNA', 'ALRN', 'ALSK', 'AM', 'AMBO', 'AMC', 'AMPE', 'AMPY', 'AMRN', 'AMRS', 'AMRX', 'AMTX', 'ANCN', 'ANH', 'ANIX', 'ANPC', 'ANTE', 'ANY', 'APDN', 'APM', 'APRE', 'APRN', 'APTO', 'APTS', 'APTX', 'APWC', 'AQMS', 'AQST', 'AR', 'ARAY', 'ARC', 'ARCO', 'ARDX', 'AREC', 'ARKO', 'ARLO', 'ARLP', 'AROC', 'ARPO', 'ARTL', 'ASC', 'ASLN', 'ASM', 'ASMB', 'ASRT', 'ASTC', 'ASX', 'ATAX', 'ATHE', 'ATHX', 'ATIF', 'ATNF', 'ATNM', 'ATOS', 'ATRS', 'ATXI', 'AUMN', 'AUTO', 'AUVI', 'AUY', 'AVCO', 'AVDL', 'AVEO', 'AVGR', 'AVXL', 'AWH', 'AWX', 'AXAS', 'AXL', 'AXU', 'AYRO', 'AYTU', 'AZRX', 'BBAR', 'BBD', 'BBGI', 'BBI', 'BBIG', 'BBVA', 'BBW', 'BCDA', 'BCLI', 'BCRX', 'BCS', 'BDR', 'BDSI', 'BEST', 'BGCP', 'BGI', 'BHAT', 'BHR', 'BHTG', 'BIMI', 'BIOC', 'BIOL', 'BKCC', 'BKD', 'BKEP', 'BKYI', 'BLCM', 'BLCT', 'BLIN', 'BLRX', 'BLU', 'BMRA', 'BNED', 'BNTC', 'BORR', 'BOXL', 'BPT', 'BPTH', 'BQ', 'BREZR', 'BRFS', 'BRN', 'BRPAR', 'BRQS', 'BRY', 'BSBR', 'BSGM', 'BSM', 'BSMX', 'BTG', 'BTU', 'BVXV', 'BW', 'BWEN', 'BXRX', 'BYFC', 'CAAP', 'CAAS', 'CALA', 'CAN', 'CANF', 'CAPR', 'CARV', 'CASA', 'CASI', 'CATB', 'CBAT', 'CBAY', 'CBIO', 'CBLI', 'CCO', 'CCRC', 'CCRN', 'CDE', 'CDEV', 'CDTX', 'CDXC', 'CEI', 'CEIX', 'CEMI', 'CERC', 'CERS', 'CETX', 'CFMS', 'CGIX', 'CHEK', 'CHMA', 'CHNR', 'CHRA', 'CHS', 'CHU', 'CIDM', 'CIG', 'CIO', 'CJJD', 'CKPT', 'CLBS', 'CLIR', 'CLNC', 'CLNY', 'CLPS', 'CLRB', 'CLS', 'CLSD', 'CLSN', 'CLVR', 'CLVS', 'CLXT', 'CMCM', 'CMO', 'CMRE', 'CMRX', 'CNDT', 'CNET', 'CNFR', 'CNSL', 'CNSP', 'CNTY', 'COCP', 'COGT', 'COMS', 'CORR', 'CPG', 'CPHI', 'CPRX', 'CPSH', 'CRBP', 'CREG', 'CREX', 'CRIS', 'CRK', 'CRKN', 'CRMD', 'CRNT', 'CSCW', 'CSLT', 'CSPR', 'CTEK', 'CTIB', 'CTIC', 'CTK', 'CTMX', 'CTRM', 'CTSO', 'CTXR', 'CVE', 'CVGI', 'CWBR', 'CX', 'CXW', 'CYCC', 'CYCN', 'CYRN', 'CYTH', 'DARE', 'DBVT', 'DFFN', 'DGLY', 'DHC', 'DHT', 'DLPN', 'DNK', 'DNN', 'DNOW', 'DOGZ', 'DPW', 'DRH', 'DRRX', 'DRTT', 'DS', 'DSKE', 'DSS', 'DSSI', 'DSX', 'DTEA', 'DTSS', 'DUO', 'DVAX', 'DXF', 'DXLG', 'DYNT', 'EARS', 'EBON', 'EBR', 'ECOR', 'EDSA', 'EGY', 'EIGR', 'ELVT', 'ELYS', 'EMAN', 'EMKR', 'EMX', 'ENBL', 'ENDP', 'ENG', 'ENIA', 'ENIC', 'ENLC', 'ENSV', 'ENTX', 'ENVB', 'ENZ', 'EOLS', 'EQ', 'EQX', 'ERF', 'ERJ', 'ESGC', 'ESTE', 'ET', 'ETM', 'ETRN', 'ETTX', 'EURN', 'EVC', 'EVFM', 'EVGN', 'EVK', 'EVOK', 'EXK', 'EXPR', 'EXTR', 'EYEG', 'EYES', 'EZGO', 'EZPW', 'FAMI', 'FBIO', 'FBP', 'FENG', 'FI', 'FINV', 'FLDM', 'FLMN', 'FLNT', 'FLY', 'FORD', 'FPAY', 'FRBK', 'FRO', 'FRSX', 'FSM', 'FSP', 'FTEK', 'FTFT', 'FTK', 'FURY', 'GAU', 'GBS', 'GCI', 'GEL', 'GEN', 'GENE', 'GEO', 'GERN', 'GFI', 'GGAL', 'GGB', 'GHSI', 'GLBS', 'GLDG', 'GLG', 'GLOG', 'GLOP', 'GLUU', 'GLYC', 'GMBL', 'GMDA', 'GMLP', 'GNCA', 'GNK', 'GNLN', 'GNPX', 'GNUS', 'GNW', 'GOGL', 'GOL', 'GORO', 'GOSS', 'GOVX', 'GPL', 'GPMT', 'GPRO', 'GRIL', 'GRNQ', 'GSAT', 'GSKY', 'GSM', 'GSS', 'GSV', 'GTE', 'GTEC', 'GTT', 'GV', 'GVP', 'HAPP', 'HBM', 'HCDI', 'HCHC', 'HDSN', 'HEPA', 'HEXO', 'HGSH', 'HIL', 'HIMX', 'HJLI', 'HL', 'HLIT', 'HLX', 'HMHC', 'HMY', 'HNRG', 'HOFV', 'HOTH', 'HSTO', 'HT', 'HTBX', 'HUGE', 'HUSA', 'HUSN', 'HX', 'HYRE', 'IAG', 'IBIO', 'ICD', 'ICON', 'ID', 'IDEX', 'IDRA', 'IFMK', 'IFRX', 'IGC', 'IHT', 'IKT', 'IMAC', 'IMGN', 'IMMP', 'IMTE', 'IMV', 'INDO', 'INFI', 'ING', 'INN', 'INOD', 'INPX', 'INUV', 'IO', 'IPDN', 'IRIX', 'ISEE', 'ISIG', 'ISR', 'ITP', 'ITRM', 'ITUB', 'IVR', 'IZEA', 'JAGX', 'JE', 'JFIN', 'JFU', 'JG', 'JIH.W', 'JILL', 'JOB', 'JUPW', 'KALA', 'KBNT', 'KBSF', 'KDMN', 'KERN', 'KGC', 'KIN', 'KIQ', 'KMPH', 'KNDI', 'KODK', 'KOPN', 'KOS', 'KRKR', 'KRMD', 'KTRA', 'KUKE', 'KXIN', 'KZIA', 'LCI', 'LCTX', 'LEAF', 'LEE', 'LGHL', 'LIFE', 'LITB', 'LIVX', 'LIZI', 'LJPC', 'LKCO', 'LLIT', 'LLNW', 'LMFA', 'LMNL', 'LODE', 'LOMA', 'LPCN', 'LPTH', 'LPTX', 'LQDA', 'LSEA', 'LTBR', 'LTRPA', 'LX', 'LXRX', 'LYG', 'MACK', 'MARK', 'MBI', 'MBII', 'MBIO', 'MBRX', 'MBT', 'MCEP', 'MCF', 'MDGS', 'MDXG', 'MEIP', 'MESA', 'MESO', 'METX', 'MFA', 'MFG', 'MFGP', 'MFH', 'MGI', 'MGY', 'MHLD', 'MICT', 'MIN', 'MIND', 'MITO', 'MITT', 'MKD', 'MKGI', 'MLND', 'MLSS', 'MNKD', 'MOGO', 'MOGU', 'MOHO', 'MOSY', 'MOTS', 'MOXC', 'MPLN', 'MRC', 'MREO', 'MRIN', 'MRKR', 'MRO', 'MSN', 'MTA', 'MTC', 'MTL', 'MTNB', 'MTP', 'MTSL', 'MUFG', 'MUX', 'MVIS', 'MYSZ', 'MYT', 'NAK', 'NAKD', 'NAOV', 'NAT', 'NAVB', 'NBEV', 'NBRV', 'NBSE', 'NBY', 'NCMI', 'NCNA', 'NDRA', 'NEOS', 'NEPT', 'NERV', 'NES', 'NEW', 'NEX', 'NG', 'NGD', 'NGL', 'NH', 'NLY', 'NMCI', 'NMRK', 'NMTR', 'NNVC', 'NOK', 'NOVN', 'NR', 'NRZ', 'NSCO', 'NSPR', 'NTEC', 'NTN', 'NURO', 'NVCN', 'NVIV', 'NWG', 'NXE', 'NXTD', 'NYMT', 'OBLG', 'OBLN', 'OBSV', 'OCG', 'OCGN', 'OCSL', 'OCX', 'OEG', 'OGEN', 'OGI', 'OIBR.C', 'OII', 'OIIM', 'OIS', 'ONCT', 'ONCY', 'ONTX', 'OPGN', 'OPK', 'OPTN', 'OPTT', 'ORBC', 'ORC', 'ORMP', 'ORN', 'ORTX', 'OSMT', 'OSW', 'OTIC', 'OTLK', 'OVID', 'OXBR', 'OXLC', 'PAA', 'PAE', 'PAGP', 'PAVM', 'PAYS', 'PBF', 'PBI', 'PDSB', 'PED', 'PEI', 'PEIX', 'PFMT', 'PGEN', 'PGRE', 'PHAS', 'PHIO', 'PHUN', 'PIRS', 'PIXY', 'PLAG', 'PLG', 'PLIN', 'PLM', 'PLYA', 'PNNT', 'POAI', 'POWW', 'PPBT', 'PPR', 'PPSI', 'PPT', 'PROG', 'PRPO', 'PRQR', 'PRTK', 'PRTY', 'PSEC', 'PSTI', 'PSTV', 'PT', 'PTE', 'PTEN', 'PTMN', 'PTN', 'PULM', 'PUMP', 'PVL', 'PXLW', 'PXS', 'QD', 'QEP', 'QIWI', 'QLGN', 'QLI', 'QTNT', 'QTT', 'QUAD', 'QUOT', 'RAIL', 'RAVE', 'RBBN', 'RCON', 'RDHL', 'REED', 'REFR', 'REI', 'REPH', 'RES', 'RESN', 'RETO', 'RFP', 'RGLS', 'RGS', 'RHE', 'RIBT', 'RIG', 'RIGL', 'RKDA', 'RLH', 'RMED', 'RMTI', 'RNWK', 'RPAI', 'RPT', 'RRC', 'RRD', 'RTLR', 'RUHN', 'RWLK', 'RWT', 'RYAM', 'SALM', 'SAN', 'SAND', 'SB', 'SBBP', 'SBS', 'SCKT', 'SCOR', 'SCYX', 'SD', 'SDPI', 'SEAC', 'SEEL', 'SELB', 'SENS', 'SESN', 'SFET', 'SFL', 'SFT', 'SGBX', 'SGLB', 'SGOC', 'SHIP', 'SID', 'SIEN', 'SIF', 'SIFY', 'SILV', 'SINO', 'SINT', 'SIOX', 'SIRI', 'SLCA', 'SLDB', 'SLGG', 'SLRX', 'SLS', 'SM', 'SMFG', 'SMSI', 'SMTS', 'SMTX', 'SNCA', 'SNCR', 'SND', 'SNDE', 'SNDL', 'SNES', 'SNGX', 'SNMP', 'SNOA', 'SNR', 'SNSS', 'SOI', 'SOLO', 'SONM', 'SONN', 'SOS', 'SPCB', 'SPPI', 'SQFT', 'SQNS', 'SREV', 'SRGA', 'SSL', 'STAF', 'STCN', 'STON', 'STSA', 'SUP', 'SUPV', 'SVM', 'SVRA', 'SWN', 'SXC', 'SXTC', 'SYBX', 'SYN', 'SYPR', 'TACO', 'TALO', 'TANH', 'TAOP', 'TAST', 'TAT', 'TATT', 'TBLT', 'TCCO', 'TCDA', 'TCON', 'TEDU', 'TEF', 'TELL', 'TENX', 'TEO', 'TGA', 'TGB', 'TGC', 'THM', 'THMO', 'TK', 'TKAT', 'TKC', 'TLGT', 'TLMD', 'TLSA', 'TLYS', 'TMBR', 'TMDI', 'TMQ', 'TMST', 'TNAV', 'TNXP', 'TOPS', 'TOUR', 'TPRE', 'TRCH', 'TRIB', 'TRIT', 'TRST', 'TRUE', 'TRVG', 'TRVN', 'TRX', 'TRXC', 'TTI', 'TTNP', 'TTOO', 'TUSK', 'TV', 'TWI', 'TWO', 'TXMD', 'TYME', 'UAMY', 'UBX', 'UEC', 'UEPS', 'UGP', 'UMC', 'UONE', 'UONEK', 'URG', 'USAS', 'USAT', 'USEG', 'USIO', 'USWS', 'USX', 'UTSI', 'UUUU', 'UWMC', 'UXIN', 'VBIV', 'VBLT', 'VCNX', 'VEDL', 'VEON', 'VERB', 'VERO', 'VERU', 'VET', 'VGZ', 'VHC', 'VIOT', 'VIRI', 'VISL', 'VIV', 'VIVE', 'VKTX', 'VNTR', 'VRA', 'VRAY', 'VSTM', 'VTGN', 'VTNR', 'VTVT', 'VVOS', 'VXRT', 'VYGR', 'VYNE', 'WATT', 'WEI', 'WETF', 'WIMI', 'WISA', 'WIT', 'WKEY', 'WMC', 'WORX', 'WPRT', 'WPX', 'WRAP', 'WRN', 'WSR', 'WTER', 'WTI', 'WTRH', 'WTTR', 'WVE', 'WWR', 'XAIR', 'XAN', 'XBIO', 'XCUR', 'XELA', 'XELB', 'XERS', 'XNET', 'XPL', 'XSPA', 'XXII', 'YCBD', 'YGYI', 'YJ', 'YPF', 'YRCW', 'YTRA', 'YVR', 'ZAGG', 'ZIOP', 'ZIXI', 'ZKIN', 'ZNGA', 'ZOM', 'ZSAN', 'ZVO', 'ZYNE', '']


class info():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.goo()

    def goo(self):
        self.x =  {'ticker':self.name, 'name':  str(yf.Ticker(self.name).info['longName'])}
        print(self.x, )
        with mylock:
            database[self.name] = self.x

def run_in_p():
    proc = []
    for name_s in stocks:
        p = Process(target=info, args=(name_s, ))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()
    print(database)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_in_p()
```

Edit:

Here's the error window that pops up
[image]

Along with this error window I get another error in the python console

```
   raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Use a task queue that has a max number of workers, probably something like `os.cpu_count()` workers.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to implement this as of yet but I'll look into that thanks @ggorlen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiprocessing Queue in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672525/multiprocessing-queue-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it crashes'? The kernel is dead or it seems to be endless?

Comment: @LumberJack I've edited the question with the error

Comment: You probably just want ``concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map``; there is no need to reinvent that. Be aware that as shown your ``database`` will not work – each process operates on a *copy* which is destroyed when the process ends.

Comment: what do you mean 'there is no need to reinvent that'? @MisterMiyagi

Comment: There are pre-existing tools for load-balanced ``for name_s in stocks: p = Process(target=info, args=(name_s, ))``, at least two in the standard library.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I’m very confused with what you’re trying to explain, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
here is one way to obtain what you want in about 2min.
Some tickers are bad, that's why it crashes.

Here's the code. I use joblib for threading or multiprocess since it doesn't work in my env. But, that's the spirit.

```
%%time
import joblib
from joblib import Parallel,delayed

WRONG_TICKERS = []
database = {}
stocks = ['AAU', 'ABEO', 'ABEV', 'ABIO', 'ABUS', 'ACCO', 'ACER', 'ACIU', 'ACOR', 'ACRX', 'ACST', 'ACTG', 'ADAP', 'ADIL', 'ADMA', 'ADMP', 'ADT', 'ADTX', 'ADXS', 'AEG', 'AEHL', 'AEHR', 'AEMD', 'AESE', 'AEY', 'AEZS', 'AFIN', 'AFMD', 'AGEN', 'AGI', 'AGRO', 'AGRX', 'AGS', 'AGTC', 'AHPI', 'AHT', 'AIHS', 'AIKI', 'AIM', 'AINC', 'AIRI', 'AIV', 'AKBA', 'AKER', 'AKTX', 'ALNA', 'ALRN', 'ALSK', 'AM', 'AMBO', 'AMC', 'AMPE', 'AMPY', 'AMRN', 'AMRS', 'AMRX', 'AMTX', 'ANCN', 'ANH', 'ANIX', 'ANPC', 'ANTE', 'ANY', 'APDN', 'APM', 'APRE', 'APRN', 'APTO', 'APTS', 'APTX', 'APWC', 'AQMS', 'AQST', 'AR', 'ARAY', 'ARC', 'ARCO', 'ARDX', 'AREC', 'ARKO', 'ARLO', 'ARLP', 'AROC', 'ARPO', 'ARTL', 'ASC', 'ASLN', 'ASM', 'ASMB', 'ASRT', 'ASTC', 'ASX', 'ATAX', 'ATHE', 'ATHX', 'ATIF', 'ATNF', 'ATNM', 'ATOS', 'ATRS', 'ATXI', 'AUMN', 'AUTO', 'AUVI', 'AUY', 'AVCO', 'AVDL', 'AVEO', 'AVGR', 'AVXL', 'AWH', 'AWX', 'AXAS', 'AXL', 'AXU', 'AYRO', 'AYTU', 'AZRX', 'BBAR', 'BBD', 'BBGI', 'BBI', 'BBIG', 'BBVA', 'BBW', 'BCDA', 'BCLI', 'BCRX', 'BCS', 'BDR', 'BDSI', 'BEST', 'BGCP', 'BGI', 'BHAT', 'BHR', 'BHTG', 'BIMI', 'BIOC', 'BIOL', 'BKCC', 'BKD', 'BKEP', 'BKYI', 'BLCM', 'BLCT', 'BLIN', 'BLRX', 'BLU', 'BMRA', 'BNED', 'BNTC', 'BORR', 'BOXL', 'BPT', 'BPTH', 'BQ', 'BREZR', 'BRFS', 'BRN', 'BRPAR', 'BRQS', 'BRY', 'BSBR', 'BSGM', 'BSM', 'BSMX', 'BTG', 'BTU', 'BVXV', 'BW', 'BWEN', 'BXRX', 'BYFC', 'CAAP', 'CAAS', 'CALA', 'CAN', 'CANF', 'CAPR', 'CARV', 'CASA', 'CASI', 'CATB', 'CBAT', 'CBAY', 'CBIO', 'CBLI', 'CCO', 'CCRC', 'CCRN', 'CDE', 'CDEV', 'CDTX', 'CDXC', 'CEI', 'CEIX', 'CEMI', 'CERC', 'CERS', 'CETX', 'CFMS', 'CGIX', 'CHEK', 'CHMA', 'CHNR', 'CHRA', 'CHS', 'CHU', 'CIDM', 'CIG', 'CIO', 'CJJD', 'CKPT', 'CLBS', 'CLIR', 'CLNC', 'CLNY', 'CLPS', 'CLRB', 'CLS', 'CLSD', 'CLSN', 'CLVR', 'CLVS', 'CLXT', 'CMCM', 'CMO', 'CMRE', 'CMRX', 'CNDT', 'CNET', 'CNFR', 'CNSL', 'CNSP', 'CNTY', 'COCP', 'COGT', 'COMS', 'CORR', 'CPG', 'CPHI', 'CPRX', 'CPSH', 'CRBP', 'CREG', 'CREX', 'CRIS', 'CRK', 'CRKN', 'CRMD', 'CRNT', 'CSCW', 'CSLT', 'CSPR', 'CTEK', 'CTIB', 'CTIC', 'CTK', 'CTMX', 'CTRM', 'CTSO', 'CTXR', 'CVE', 'CVGI', 'CWBR', 'CX', 'CXW', 'CYCC', 'CYCN', 'CYRN', 'CYTH', 'DARE', 'DBVT', 'DFFN', 'DGLY', 'DHC', 'DHT', 'DLPN', 'DNK', 'DNN', 'DNOW', 'DOGZ', 'DPW', 'DRH', 'DRRX', 'DRTT', 'DS', 'DSKE', 'DSS', 'DSSI', 'DSX', 'DTEA', 'DTSS', 'DUO', 'DVAX', 'DXF', 'DXLG', 'DYNT', 'EARS', 'EBON', 'EBR', 'ECOR', 'EDSA', 'EGY', 'EIGR', 'ELVT', 'ELYS', 'EMAN', 'EMKR', 'EMX', 'ENBL', 'ENDP', 'ENG', 'ENIA', 'ENIC', 'ENLC', 'ENSV', 'ENTX', 'ENVB', 'ENZ', 'EOLS', 'EQ', 'EQX', 'ERF', 'ERJ', 'ESGC', 'ESTE', 'ET', 'ETM', 'ETRN', 'ETTX', 'EURN', 'EVC', 'EVFM', 'EVGN', 'EVK', 'EVOK', 'EXK', 'EXPR', 'EXTR', 'EYEG', 'EYES', 'EZGO', 'EZPW', 'FAMI', 'FBIO', 'FBP', 'FENG', 'FI', 'FINV', 'FLDM', 'FLMN', 'FLNT', 'FLY', 'FORD', 'FPAY', 'FRBK', 'FRO', 'FRSX', 'FSM', 'FSP', 'FTEK', 'FTFT', 'FTK', 'FURY', 'GAU', 'GBS', 'GCI', 'GEL', 'GEN', 'GENE', 'GEO', 'GERN', 'GFI', 'GGAL', 'GGB', 'GHSI', 'GLBS', 'GLDG', 'GLG', 'GLOG', 'GLOP', 'GLUU', 'GLYC', 'GMBL', 'GMDA', 'GMLP', 'GNCA', 'GNK', 'GNLN', 'GNPX', 'GNUS', 'GNW', 'GOGL', 'GOL', 'GORO', 'GOSS', 'GOVX', 'GPL', 'GPMT', 'GPRO', 'GRIL', 'GRNQ', 'GSAT', 'GSKY', 'GSM', 'GSS', 'GSV', 'GTE', 'GTEC', 'GTT', 'GV', 'GVP', 'HAPP', 'HBM', 'HCDI', 'HCHC', 'HDSN', 'HEPA', 'HEXO', 'HGSH', 'HIL', 'HIMX', 'HJLI', 'HL', 'HLIT', 'HLX', 'HMHC', 'HMY', 'HNRG', 'HOFV', 'HOTH', 'HSTO', 'HT', 'HTBX', 'HUGE', 'HUSA', 'HUSN', 'HX', 'HYRE', 'IAG', 'IBIO', 'ICD', 'ICON', 'ID', 'IDEX', 'IDRA', 'IFMK', 'IFRX', 'IGC', 'IHT', 'IKT', 'IMAC', 'IMGN', 'IMMP', 'IMTE', 'IMV', 'INDO', 'INFI', 'ING', 'INN', 'INOD', 'INPX', 'INUV', 'IO', 'IPDN', 'IRIX', 'ISEE', 'ISIG', 'ISR', 'ITP', 'ITRM', 'ITUB', 'IVR', 'IZEA', 'JAGX', 'JE', 'JFIN', 'JFU', 'JG', 'JIH.W', 'JILL', 'JOB', 'JUPW', 'KALA', 'KBNT', 'KBSF', 'KDMN', 'KERN', 'KGC', 'KIN', 'KIQ', 'KMPH', 'KNDI', 'KODK', 'KOPN', 'KOS', 'KRKR', 'KRMD', 'KTRA', 'KUKE', 'KXIN', 'KZIA', 'LCI', 'LCTX', 'LEAF', 'LEE', 'LGHL', 'LIFE', 'LITB', 'LIVX', 'LIZI', 'LJPC', 'LKCO', 'LLIT', 'LLNW', 'LMFA', 'LMNL', 'LODE', 'LOMA', 'LPCN', 'LPTH', 'LPTX', 'LQDA', 'LSEA', 'LTBR', 'LTRPA', 'LX', 'LXRX', 'LYG', 'MACK', 'MARK', 'MBI', 'MBII', 'MBIO', 'MBRX', 'MBT', 'MCEP', 'MCF', 'MDGS', 'MDXG', 'MEIP', 'MESA', 'MESO', 'METX', 'MFA', 'MFG', 'MFGP', 'MFH', 'MGI', 'MGY', 'MHLD', 'MICT', 'MIN', 'MIND', 'MITO', 'MITT', 'MKD', 'MKGI', 'MLND', 'MLSS', 'MNKD', 'MOGO', 'MOGU', 'MOHO', 'MOSY', 'MOTS', 'MOXC', 'MPLN', 'MRC', 'MREO', 'MRIN', 'MRKR', 'MRO', 'MSN', 'MTA', 'MTC', 'MTL', 'MTNB', 'MTP', 'MTSL', 'MUFG', 'MUX', 'MVIS', 'MYSZ', 'MYT', 'NAK', 'NAKD', 'NAOV', 'NAT', 'NAVB', 'NBEV', 'NBRV', 'NBSE', 'NBY', 'NCMI', 'NCNA', 'NDRA', 'NEOS', 'NEPT', 'NERV', 'NES', 'NEW', 'NEX', 'NG', 'NGD', 'NGL', 'NH', 'NLY', 'NMCI', 'NMRK', 'NMTR', 'NNVC', 'NOK', 'NOVN', 'NR', 'NRZ', 'NSCO', 'NSPR', 'NTEC', 'NTN', 'NURO', 'NVCN', 'NVIV', 'NWG', 'NXE', 'NXTD', 'NYMT', 'OBLG', 'OBLN', 'OBSV', 'OCG', 'OCGN', 'OCSL', 'OCX', 'OEG', 'OGEN', 'OGI', 'OIBR.C', 'OII', 'OIIM', 'OIS', 'ONCT', 'ONCY', 'ONTX', 'OPGN', 'OPK', 'OPTN', 'OPTT', 'ORBC', 'ORC', 'ORMP', 'ORN', 'ORTX', 'OSMT', 'OSW', 'OTIC', 'OTLK', 'OVID', 'OXBR', 'OXLC', 'PAA', 'PAE', 'PAGP', 'PAVM', 'PAYS', 'PBF', 'PBI', 'PDSB', 'PED', 'PEI', 'PEIX', 'PFMT', 'PGEN', 'PGRE', 'PHAS', 'PHIO', 'PHUN', 'PIRS', 'PIXY', 'PLAG', 'PLG', 'PLIN', 'PLM', 'PLYA', 'PNNT', 'POAI', 'POWW', 'PPBT', 'PPR', 'PPSI', 'PPT', 'PROG', 'PRPO', 'PRQR', 'PRTK', 'PRTY', 'PSEC', 'PSTI', 'PSTV', 'PT', 'PTE', 'PTEN', 'PTMN', 'PTN', 'PULM', 'PUMP', 'PVL', 'PXLW', 'PXS', 'QD', 'QEP', 'QIWI', 'QLGN', 'QLI', 'QTNT', 'QTT', 'QUAD', 'QUOT', 'RAIL', 'RAVE', 'RBBN', 'RCON', 'RDHL', 'REED', 'REFR', 'REI', 'REPH', 'RES', 'RESN', 'RETO', 'RFP', 'RGLS', 'RGS', 'RHE', 'RIBT', 'RIG', 'RIGL', 'RKDA', 'RLH', 'RMED', 'RMTI', 'RNWK', 'RPAI', 'RPT', 'RRC', 'RRD', 'RTLR', 'RUHN', 'RWLK', 'RWT', 'RYAM', 'SALM', 'SAN', 'SAND', 'SB', 'SBBP', 'SBS', 'SCKT', 'SCOR', 'SCYX', 'SD', 'SDPI', 'SEAC', 'SEEL', 'SELB', 'SENS', 'SESN', 'SFET', 'SFL', 'SFT', 'SGBX', 'SGLB', 'SGOC', 'SHIP', 'SID', 'SIEN', 'SIF', 'SIFY', 'SILV', 'SINO', 'SINT', 'SIOX', 'SIRI', 'SLCA', 'SLDB', 'SLGG', 'SLRX', 'SLS', 'SM', 'SMFG', 'SMSI', 'SMTS', 'SMTX', 'SNCA', 'SNCR', 'SND', 'SNDE', 'SNDL', 'SNES', 'SNGX', 'SNMP', 'SNOA', 'SNR', 'SNSS', 'SOI', 'SOLO', 'SONM', 'SONN', 'SOS', 'SPCB', 'SPPI', 'SQFT', 'SQNS', 'SREV', 'SRGA', 'SSL', 'STAF', 'STCN', 'STON', 'STSA', 'SUP', 'SUPV', 'SVM', 'SVRA', 'SWN', 'SXC', 'SXTC', 'SYBX', 'SYN', 'SYPR', 'TACO', 'TALO', 'TANH', 'TAOP', 'TAST', 'TAT', 'TATT', 'TBLT', 'TCCO', 'TCDA', 'TCON', 'TEDU', 'TEF', 'TELL', 'TENX', 'TEO', 'TGA', 'TGB', 'TGC', 'THM', 'THMO', 'TK', 'TKAT', 'TKC', 'TLGT', 'TLMD', 'TLSA', 'TLYS', 'TMBR', 'TMDI', 'TMQ', 'TMST', 'TNAV', 'TNXP', 'TOPS', 'TOUR', 'TPRE', 'TRCH', 'TRIB', 'TRIT', 'TRST', 'TRUE', 'TRVG', 'TRVN', 'TRX', 'TRXC', 'TTI', 'TTNP', 'TTOO', 'TUSK', 'TV', 'TWI', 'TWO', 'TXMD', 'TYME', 'UAMY', 'UBX', 'UEC', 'UEPS', 'UGP', 'UMC', 'UONE', 'UONEK', 'URG', 'USAS', 'USAT', 'USEG', 'USIO', 'USWS', 'USX', 'UTSI', 'UUUU', 'UWMC', 'UXIN', 'VBIV', 'VBLT', 'VCNX', 'VEDL', 'VEON', 'VERB', 'VERO', 'VERU', 'VET', 'VGZ', 'VHC', 'VIOT', 'VIRI', 'VISL', 'VIV', 'VIVE', 'VKTX', 'VNTR', 'VRA', 'VRAY', 'VSTM', 'VTGN', 'VTNR', 'VTVT', 'VVOS', 'VXRT', 'VYGR', 'VYNE', 'WATT', 'WEI', 'WETF', 'WIMI', 'WISA', 'WIT', 'WKEY', 'WMC', 'WORX', 'WPRT', 'WPX', 'WRAP', 'WRN', 'WSR', 'WTER', 'WTI', 'WTRH', 'WTTR', 'WVE', 'WWR', 'XAIR', 'XAN', 'XBIO', 'XCUR', 'XELA', 'XELB', 'XERS', 'XNET', 'XPL', 'XSPA', 'XXII', 'YCBD', 'YGYI', 'YJ', 'YPF', 'YRCW', 'YTRA', 'YVR', 'ZAGG', 'ZIOP', 'ZIXI', 'ZKIN', 'ZNGA', 'ZOM', 'ZSAN', 'ZVO', 'ZYNE']


def get_name(_ticker):
    try:
        database[_ticker] = yf.Ticker(_ticker).info['longName']
    except:
        WRONG_TICKERS.append(_ticker)
        pass
    return(database)

number_of_cpu = joblib.cpu_count()
delayed_funcs = [delayed(get_name)(_ticker) for _ticker in stocks]
parallel_pool = Parallel(n_jobs=number_of_cpu,prefer="threads") # processes threads
parallel_pool(delayed_funcs)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Note that depending on your computer, it could be faster withe 'processes' instead of 'threads'. You have to test to know it.

Edit : When re-running the same code, everything is in 404 ERROR. Bust be a problem with yfinance

Edit 2 : It's okay again...

Comment: although when running this, my computer is quieter and I feel as if the computer isn't used to its maximum potential, is there a way to speed the script up

Comment: As I told you, you can test with 'process' instead of 'treads' to see which one is the fastest. More than that, I don't see how to increase... Sorry.

Comment: I tried both, wasn't really a big difference, but then I changed the number of workers and it increased significantly

Comment: You're right. The most you can get on it, the best it is. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer a solution using a package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  Disclaimer:  I am the author of the package.  You can get that same data in a few seconds with the following:

```
from yahooquery import Ticker

stocks = ['AAU', 'ABEO', 'ABEV', 'ABIO', 'ABUS', 'ACCO', 'ACER', 'ACIU', 'ACOR', 'ACRX', 'ACST', 'ACTG', 'ADAP', 'ADIL', 'ADMA', 'ADMP', 'ADT', 'ADTX', 'ADXS', 'AEG', 'AEHL', 'AEHR', 'AEMD', 'AESE', 'AEY', 'AEZS', 'AFIN', 'AFMD', 'AGEN', 'AGI', 'AGRO', 'AGRX', 'AGS', 'AGTC', 'AHPI', 'AHT', 'AIHS', 'AIKI', 'AIM', 'AINC', 'AIRI', 'AIV', 'AKBA', 'AKER', 'AKTX', 'ALNA', 'ALRN', 'ALSK', 'AM', 'AMBO', 'AMC', 'AMPE', 'AMPY', 'AMRN', 'AMRS', 'AMRX', 'AMTX', 'ANCN', 'ANH', 'ANIX', 'ANPC', 'ANTE', 'ANY', 'APDN', 'APM', 'APRE', 'APRN', 'APTO', 'APTS', 'APTX', 'APWC', 'AQMS', 'AQST', 'AR', 'ARAY', 'ARC', 'ARCO', 'ARDX', 'AREC', 'ARKO', 'ARLO', 'ARLP', 'AROC', 'ARPO', 'ARTL', 'ASC', 'ASLN', 'ASM', 'ASMB', 'ASRT', 'ASTC', 'ASX', 'ATAX', 'ATHE', 'ATHX', 'ATIF', 'ATNF', 'ATNM', 'ATOS', 'ATRS', 'ATXI', 'AUMN', 'AUTO', 'AUVI', 'AUY', 'AVCO', 'AVDL', 'AVEO', 'AVGR', 'AVXL', 'AWH', 'AWX', 'AXAS', 'AXL', 'AXU', 'AYRO', 'AYTU', 'AZRX', 'BBAR', 'BBD', 'BBGI', 'BBI', 'BBIG', 'BBVA', 'BBW', 'BCDA', 'BCLI', 'BCRX', 'BCS', 'BDR', 'BDSI', 'BEST', 'BGCP', 'BGI', 'BHAT', 'BHR', 'BHTG', 'BIMI', 'BIOC', 'BIOL', 'BKCC', 'BKD', 'BKEP', 'BKYI', 'BLCM', 'BLCT', 'BLIN', 'BLRX', 'BLU', 'BMRA', 'BNED', 'BNTC', 'BORR', 'BOXL', 'BPT', 'BPTH', 'BQ', 'BREZR', 'BRFS', 'BRN', 'BRPAR', 'BRQS', 'BRY', 'BSBR', 'BSGM', 'BSM', 'BSMX', 'BTG', 'BTU', 'BVXV', 'BW', 'BWEN', 'BXRX', 'BYFC', 'CAAP', 'CAAS', 'CALA', 'CAN', 'CANF', 'CAPR', 'CARV', 'CASA', 'CASI', 'CATB', 'CBAT', 'CBAY', 'CBIO', 'CBLI', 'CCO', 'CCRC', 'CCRN', 'CDE', 'CDEV', 'CDTX', 'CDXC', 'CEI', 'CEIX', 'CEMI', 'CERC', 'CERS', 'CETX', 'CFMS', 'CGIX', 'CHEK', 'CHMA', 'CHNR', 'CHRA', 'CHS', 'CHU', 'CIDM', 'CIG', 'CIO', 'CJJD', 'CKPT', 'CLBS', 'CLIR', 'CLNC', 'CLNY', 'CLPS', 'CLRB', 'CLS', 'CLSD', 'CLSN', 'CLVR', 'CLVS', 'CLXT', 'CMCM', 'CMO', 'CMRE', 'CMRX', 'CNDT', 'CNET', 'CNFR', 'CNSL', 'CNSP', 'CNTY', 'COCP', 'COGT', 'COMS', 'CORR', 'CPG', 'CPHI', 'CPRX', 'CPSH', 'CRBP', 'CREG', 'CREX', 'CRIS', 'CRK', 'CRKN', 'CRMD', 'CRNT', 'CSCW', 'CSLT', 'CSPR', 'CTEK', 'CTIB', 'CTIC', 'CTK', 'CTMX', 'CTRM', 'CTSO', 'CTXR', 'CVE', 'CVGI', 'CWBR', 'CX', 'CXW', 'CYCC', 'CYCN', 'CYRN', 'CYTH', 'DARE', 'DBVT', 'DFFN', 'DGLY', 'DHC', 'DHT', 'DLPN', 'DNK', 'DNN', 'DNOW', 'DOGZ', 'DPW', 'DRH', 'DRRX', 'DRTT', 'DS', 'DSKE', 'DSS', 'DSSI', 'DSX', 'DTEA', 'DTSS', 'DUO', 'DVAX', 'DXF', 'DXLG', 'DYNT', 'EARS', 'EBON', 'EBR', 'ECOR', 'EDSA', 'EGY', 'EIGR', 'ELVT', 'ELYS', 'EMAN', 'EMKR', 'EMX', 'ENBL', 'ENDP', 'ENG', 'ENIA', 'ENIC', 'ENLC', 'ENSV', 'ENTX', 'ENVB', 'ENZ', 'EOLS', 'EQ', 'EQX', 'ERF', 'ERJ', 'ESGC', 'ESTE', 'ET', 'ETM', 'ETRN', 'ETTX', 'EURN', 'EVC', 'EVFM', 'EVGN', 'EVK', 'EVOK', 'EXK', 'EXPR', 'EXTR', 'EYEG', 'EYES', 'EZGO', 'EZPW', 'FAMI', 'FBIO', 'FBP', 'FENG', 'FI', 'FINV', 'FLDM', 'FLMN', 'FLNT', 'FLY', 'FORD', 'FPAY', 'FRBK', 'FRO', 'FRSX', 'FSM', 'FSP', 'FTEK', 'FTFT', 'FTK', 'FURY', 'GAU', 'GBS', 'GCI', 'GEL', 'GEN', 'GENE', 'GEO', 'GERN', 'GFI', 'GGAL', 'GGB', 'GHSI', 'GLBS', 'GLDG', 'GLG', 'GLOG', 'GLOP', 'GLUU', 'GLYC', 'GMBL', 'GMDA', 'GMLP', 'GNCA', 'GNK', 'GNLN', 'GNPX', 'GNUS', 'GNW', 'GOGL', 'GOL', 'GORO', 'GOSS', 'GOVX', 'GPL', 'GPMT', 'GPRO', 'GRIL', 'GRNQ', 'GSAT', 'GSKY', 'GSM', 'GSS', 'GSV', 'GTE', 'GTEC', 'GTT', 'GV', 'GVP', 'HAPP', 'HBM', 'HCDI', 'HCHC', 'HDSN', 'HEPA', 'HEXO', 'HGSH', 'HIL', 'HIMX', 'HJLI', 'HL', 'HLIT', 'HLX', 'HMHC', 'HMY', 'HNRG', 'HOFV', 'HOTH', 'HSTO', 'HT', 'HTBX', 'HUGE', 'HUSA', 'HUSN', 'HX', 'HYRE', 'IAG', 'IBIO', 'ICD', 'ICON', 'ID', 'IDEX', 'IDRA', 'IFMK', 'IFRX', 'IGC', 'IHT', 'IKT', 'IMAC', 'IMGN', 'IMMP', 'IMTE', 'IMV', 'INDO', 'INFI', 'ING', 'INN', 'INOD', 'INPX', 'INUV', 'IO', 'IPDN', 'IRIX', 'ISEE', 'ISIG', 'ISR', 'ITP', 'ITRM', 'ITUB', 'IVR', 'IZEA', 'JAGX', 'JE', 'JFIN', 'JFU', 'JG', 'JIH.W', 'JILL', 'JOB', 'JUPW', 'KALA', 'KBNT', 'KBSF', 'KDMN', 'KERN', 'KGC', 'KIN', 'KIQ', 'KMPH', 'KNDI', 'KODK', 'KOPN', 'KOS', 'KRKR', 'KRMD', 'KTRA', 'KUKE', 'KXIN', 'KZIA', 'LCI', 'LCTX', 'LEAF', 'LEE', 'LGHL', 'LIFE', 'LITB', 'LIVX', 'LIZI', 'LJPC', 'LKCO', 'LLIT', 'LLNW', 'LMFA', 'LMNL', 'LODE', 'LOMA', 'LPCN', 'LPTH', 'LPTX', 'LQDA', 'LSEA', 'LTBR', 'LTRPA', 'LX', 'LXRX', 'LYG', 'MACK', 'MARK', 'MBI', 'MBII', 'MBIO', 'MBRX', 'MBT', 'MCEP', 'MCF', 'MDGS', 'MDXG', 'MEIP', 'MESA', 'MESO', 'METX', 'MFA', 'MFG', 'MFGP', 'MFH', 'MGI', 'MGY', 'MHLD', 'MICT', 'MIN', 'MIND', 'MITO', 'MITT', 'MKD', 'MKGI', 'MLND', 'MLSS', 'MNKD', 'MOGO', 'MOGU', 'MOHO', 'MOSY', 'MOTS', 'MOXC', 'MPLN', 'MRC', 'MREO', 'MRIN', 'MRKR', 'MRO', 'MSN', 'MTA', 'MTC', 'MTL', 'MTNB', 'MTP', 'MTSL', 'MUFG', 'MUX', 'MVIS', 'MYSZ', 'MYT', 'NAK', 'NAKD', 'NAOV', 'NAT', 'NAVB', 'NBEV', 'NBRV', 'NBSE', 'NBY', 'NCMI', 'NCNA', 'NDRA', 'NEOS', 'NEPT', 'NERV', 'NES', 'NEW', 'NEX', 'NG', 'NGD', 'NGL', 'NH', 'NLY', 'NMCI', 'NMRK', 'NMTR', 'NNVC', 'NOK', 'NOVN', 'NR', 'NRZ', 'NSCO', 'NSPR', 'NTEC', 'NTN', 'NURO', 'NVCN', 'NVIV', 'NWG', 'NXE', 'NXTD', 'NYMT', 'OBLG', 'OBLN', 'OBSV', 'OCG', 'OCGN', 'OCSL', 'OCX', 'OEG', 'OGEN', 'OGI', 'OIBR.C', 'OII', 'OIIM', 'OIS', 'ONCT', 'ONCY', 'ONTX', 'OPGN', 'OPK', 'OPTN', 'OPTT', 'ORBC', 'ORC', 'ORMP', 'ORN', 'ORTX', 'OSMT', 'OSW', 'OTIC', 'OTLK', 'OVID', 'OXBR', 'OXLC', 'PAA', 'PAE', 'PAGP', 'PAVM', 'PAYS', 'PBF', 'PBI', 'PDSB', 'PED', 'PEI', 'PEIX', 'PFMT', 'PGEN', 'PGRE', 'PHAS', 'PHIO', 'PHUN', 'PIRS', 'PIXY', 'PLAG', 'PLG', 'PLIN', 'PLM', 'PLYA', 'PNNT', 'POAI', 'POWW', 'PPBT', 'PPR', 'PPSI', 'PPT', 'PROG', 'PRPO', 'PRQR', 'PRTK', 'PRTY', 'PSEC', 'PSTI', 'PSTV', 'PT', 'PTE', 'PTEN', 'PTMN', 'PTN', 'PULM', 'PUMP', 'PVL', 'PXLW', 'PXS', 'QD', 'QEP', 'QIWI', 'QLGN', 'QLI', 'QTNT', 'QTT', 'QUAD', 'QUOT', 'RAIL', 'RAVE', 'RBBN', 'RCON', 'RDHL', 'REED', 'REFR', 'REI', 'REPH', 'RES', 'RESN', 'RETO', 'RFP', 'RGLS', 'RGS', 'RHE', 'RIBT', 'RIG', 'RIGL', 'RKDA', 'RLH', 'RMED', 'RMTI', 'RNWK', 'RPAI', 'RPT', 'RRC', 'RRD', 'RTLR', 'RUHN', 'RWLK', 'RWT', 'RYAM', 'SALM', 'SAN', 'SAND', 'SB', 'SBBP', 'SBS', 'SCKT', 'SCOR', 'SCYX', 'SD', 'SDPI', 'SEAC', 'SEEL', 'SELB', 'SENS', 'SESN', 'SFET', 'SFL', 'SFT', 'SGBX', 'SGLB', 'SGOC', 'SHIP', 'SID', 'SIEN', 'SIF', 'SIFY', 'SILV', 'SINO', 'SINT', 'SIOX', 'SIRI', 'SLCA', 'SLDB', 'SLGG', 'SLRX', 'SLS', 'SM', 'SMFG', 'SMSI', 'SMTS', 'SMTX', 'SNCA', 'SNCR', 'SND', 'SNDE', 'SNDL', 'SNES', 'SNGX', 'SNMP', 'SNOA', 'SNR', 'SNSS', 'SOI', 'SOLO', 'SONM', 'SONN', 'SOS', 'SPCB', 'SPPI', 'SQFT', 'SQNS', 'SREV', 'SRGA', 'SSL', 'STAF', 'STCN', 'STON', 'STSA', 'SUP', 'SUPV', 'SVM', 'SVRA', 'SWN', 'SXC', 'SXTC', 'SYBX', 'SYN', 'SYPR', 'TACO', 'TALO', 'TANH', 'TAOP', 'TAST', 'TAT', 'TATT', 'TBLT', 'TCCO', 'TCDA', 'TCON', 'TEDU', 'TEF', 'TELL', 'TENX', 'TEO', 'TGA', 'TGB', 'TGC', 'THM', 'THMO', 'TK', 'TKAT', 'TKC', 'TLGT', 'TLMD', 'TLSA', 'TLYS', 'TMBR', 'TMDI', 'TMQ', 'TMST', 'TNAV', 'TNXP', 'TOPS', 'TOUR', 'TPRE', 'TRCH', 'TRIB', 'TRIT', 'TRST', 'TRUE', 'TRVG', 'TRVN', 'TRX', 'TRXC', 'TTI', 'TTNP', 'TTOO', 'TUSK', 'TV', 'TWI', 'TWO', 'TXMD', 'TYME', 'UAMY', 'UBX', 'UEC', 'UEPS', 'UGP', 'UMC', 'UONE', 'UONEK', 'URG', 'USAS', 'USAT', 'USEG', 'USIO', 'USWS', 'USX', 'UTSI', 'UUUU', 'UWMC', 'UXIN', 'VBIV', 'VBLT', 'VCNX', 'VEDL', 'VEON', 'VERB', 'VERO', 'VERU', 'VET', 'VGZ', 'VHC', 'VIOT', 'VIRI', 'VISL', 'VIV', 'VIVE', 'VKTX', 'VNTR', 'VRA', 'VRAY', 'VSTM', 'VTGN', 'VTNR', 'VTVT', 'VVOS', 'VXRT', 'VYGR', 'VYNE', 'WATT', 'WEI', 'WETF', 'WIMI', 'WISA', 'WIT', 'WKEY', 'WMC', 'WORX', 'WPRT', 'WPX', 'WRAP', 'WRN', 'WSR', 'WTER', 'WTI', 'WTRH', 'WTTR', 'WVE', 'WWR', 'XAIR', 'XAN', 'XBIO', 'XCUR', 'XELA', 'XELB', 'XERS', 'XNET', 'XPL', 'XSPA', 'XXII', 'YCBD', 'YGYI', 'YJ', 'YPF', 'YRCW', 'YTRA', 'YVR', 'ZAGG', 'ZIOP', 'ZIXI', 'ZKIN', 'ZNGA', 'ZOM', 'ZSAN', 'ZVO', 'ZYNE', '']

# validate is optional but will go through your list and keep only valid symbols
t = Ticker(symbols, validate=True)
data = t.quotes
d = {k: v['longName'] for k, v in data.items()}
```

Comment: wow this was super quick, thankyou. Is there any documentation for this package?

Comment: I found the documentation thanks, can I used this many times or will my IP be blocked

Comment: Does the package also fetch the current price ?

Comment: The `regularMarketPrice` is a key that's returned from the `quotes` method - https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/guide/ticker/miscellaneous/#quotes